# python scipy/facile optimization help: unsure how to structure the logic

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming, maximize

I'm trying to perform optimization on a sum and just can't figure out how to properly write the code. Checked a bunch of other threads on scipy.optimization.minimize .linprog , etc but still having trouble. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction with explanations.

**My objective:** I have the following tables of different lengths as below in the code. I want my algorithm to choose 2 rows from A, 3 rows from B, 2 rows from C, 1 row from D, and 1 row from E. It can't pick the same entry twice. I want to optimize for the maximum sum of x from all the row choices but put a constraint on the respective sum of y such that it doesn't exceed 4. Also, for whatever label2 of the row picked in column D, I want all rows in all the other tables with that value in label1 to be excluded from selection. Really struggling with this last one...

Summary: Want max(sum(x)) st sum(y) < 4 and label2 of chosen value of table D is not an element of chosen values of table A,B,C,E.

The output should be the rows chosen.

Appreciate any help! Just can't seem to wrap my head around this and its been bothering me for days now. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def make_table(x):
    categories = ['a','b','c','d','e']
    labels = []

    for i in range(0,x):
        j = np.random.choice(5, 2, replace=False)
        labels.append([categories[j[0]],categories[j[1]]])


    X1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.randn(x),
    'y': np.random.randn(x)
    })

    X2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(labels), columns=['label1','label2'])

    return pd.concat([X2,X1], axis=1)

A = make_table(50)
B = make_table(100)
C = make_table(50)
D = make_table(25)
E = A+B+C+D

Sample table (only showing first 6 rows. All tables look like this though):
label1 label2         x         y
e      a  0.394106  1.961436
a      b -0.802064  0.051326
a      e  1.819099 -1.205606
e      b  0.792452 -0.535669
b      d -1.290806 -1.146422
a      b -0.530618 -0.871684
...
```

Comment: It's hard to grasp the task. You probably should be much more precise and formal (maths). But it sounds like a discrete-optimization problem where scipy won't help much. You probably have to switch to [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) (which supports mixed-integer programming).

Comment: Added a sample of the tables I'm working with and also a summary at the top. Hope that makes it more clear. I'll check out pulp. Thanks for the recommendation! Open to other comments~